# QT Performance Enable/Disable Widgets

Tags: performance, qt, qt5, windows-8.1, qwidget

i use qt 5.0.2 on windows 8.1 64bit

In my app i select items in a listwidget. after each selection some slots are triggered and widgets like comboboxes and tables are disabled or enabled. i also refill headers of the tables with stringlist or change flags of each table item.

i noticed that when im selecting items fast there is a delay between selection and display of the changed data.
this delay increases (up to 1 second) with the number of widgets im updating.

my question is, if enabling/disabling widgets can usually cause noticeable performance losses in qt.

Answer (score 1):

Hack: you should not update state of your model without emitting `dataChanged()` on each item. It's very slow for `QTreeView` (about 0.5 secs in debug mode for 10k items on my PC).

So solution is:

1. Update your item states manually, not throught item model
2. `emit dataChanged( QModelIndex(), QModelIndex() ); // hack :)`

It is prefferable to use [Qt MVC](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html) instead of list widgets, because QListWidget is not designed for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Disable/enable QWidgets lead to updating widget appearance and take some effort, but not such bad.

In your app listwidget and other widgets are all updating, so the updating performance can also be caused by list widget.

to rule out listwidget you can test use some QPushbuttons to switch a bunch of widgets.

Also, is QGraphicsView/Scene, or complex delegate, or custom painting used?

Comment: i dont use such thing. yes its possible that the listwidget itself cause that problems, but its hard to identify.

Comment: its very strange because a other teammember is running the app with mac and there are no performance problems